# Let there be [contributions]

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, there are [102 questions](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=contribution%20is%3Aquestion) containing "contribution". Thus, I hereby propose that tag [contributions](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contributions) be created.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this tag is not a good idea, because one could rephrase almost any type of scientific work as "a contribution to [...]". Therefore, this tag would not convey any meaningful information.